# Using i18n in SilverStripe template

Tags: silverstripe

I'm using SilverStripe 3.7.1 and PHP 7.2. To translate string in my template I use syntax

```
<%t Namespace.Entity "String_to_translate" %>
```

When length of the "String_to_translate" is more than 2045 symbols I get error:

```
[26-Jul-2018 10:18:33] Error at framework/view/SSTemplateParser.php line 4028: Uncaught SSTemplateParseException: Parse error in template on line 163. Error was: Malformed opening block tag t. Perhaps you have tried to use operators?
```

Can I change the maximum length of the string to translate?

Comment: Good question! I suggest you raise this as an issue on the [silverstripe/framework](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/new) module, since it sounds like a bug in core